# quiero crear un script dentro de Unity para vincularlo a un botón y al dar click de la escena 1 me envíe a la escena dos

Tags: unity

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cual seria el código cuando haga el script para cambiar de escena a escena por ejemplo realice  el de url pero como podría escribir el código  para cambiar de escena 1 a escena 2 hasta la 4 [image: la imagen dos es el ejemplo del script Url]

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Qué intentaste? ¿Leíste la documentación? Si no es así te doy una pista por dónde empezar: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html

Comment: El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

La función del script podría ser esta:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("NombreEscena",LoadSceneMode.Single);
```

Luego tendrías que añadir la llamada a la función que tenga esta sentencia desde el OnClick() del componente Button.